# Audio stream playing in React app with a websocket connection

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, streaming

I am sending an audio to websockets server, which responds with a stream. Since data comes in chunks, I am not able to play it seamlessly in the browsers, as new data gets appended to the existing audioBlob. I am not a novice React or Front-end for that matter, so if anyone could recommend how to change this part of code posted below wd be appreciated

When we get an image from server, we could directly feed an endpoint from server so that data comes neatly, if there's something similar, please suggest, will update my server side code if necessary. Using Nodes.js `ws` library on the backend

My current (inefficient code) :(

```
`useEffect(() => {
        if (lastMessage && audioRef.current) {
          stopTimer();
          setUploading(false);
      
          const newAudioData = new Blob([lastMessage.data], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
          if (!audioBlob) {
            setAudioBlob(newAudioData);
            audioRef.current.src = URL.createObjectURL(newAudioData);
            //audioRef.current.play();
          } else {
            setCurrentBit(audioRef.current.currentTime)
            const updatedAudioData = new Blob([audioBlob, newAudioData], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
            setAudioBlob(updatedAudioData);
            audioRef.current.src = URL.createObjectURL(updatedAudioData);
          }

          if (!startedPlay) {
            audioRef.current.play();
            setStartedPlay(true);
          } else {
            audioRef.current.currentTime = currentBit;
            audioRef.current.play();
          }
        }
      }, [lastMessage]);
```